# wordpress - how to index categories in google?

Tags: wordpress, indexing, categories

I was wondering how I could show categories in google search, I mean like the ones you see under the main link if you search cnn or something else (world-videos etc).

Like in this img
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ABHIb.png

Answer (score 0):

those are so-called google sitelinks... read more about it here at [google support](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en)